# Verificar valor do $_SESSION['logout'] sem atualizar a página

Tags: php, javascript

Estou tentando fazer um redirecionamento quando o `$_SESSION['logout']` for igual a `on`. Porém ele só verifica o valor do `$_SESSION['logout']` ao atualizar a página.

Gostaria de saber como ficar verificando o valor do `$_SESSION['logout']` a cada 5 segundos sem recarregar a página, e quando o valor dele for `on` ele redirecionar.

```
if($_SESSION['logout'] == "on") {

  echo "<script type=\"text/javascript\">
  window.location = 'login.php';
  </script>";

}
```

Comment: Isso, verificar a cada 5 segundos por exemplo.

Comment: Apaguei os meus comentários, já que formulei a resposta. Se lhe servir, aceite-a como solução para futuros membros. Se lhe faltar algo, pode comentar na resposta que irei revisar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> "*- Gostaria de saber como ficar verificando o valor do $_SESSION['logout'] a cada 5 segundos sem recarregar a página, e quando o valor dele for on ele redirecionar.*"

Isso pode ser feito com requisições *ajax* executado dentro de uma função `setInterval()`. Veja meu exemplo:

**index.php:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Verificar valor de $_SESSION['logout'] por LipESprY</title>

        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>

    </head>
    <body>
        <p>Uma página qualquer...</p>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(function(){
                setInterval(function(){
                    $.ajax({
                        url: 'logout_status.php',
                        method: 'get',
                        dataType: 'json'
                    })
                    .done(function(retorno){
                        if (retorno.logout == 'on')
                            window.location.href = 'login.php';
                    })
                    .fail(function(erro){
                        console.log('Ocorreu um erro ao checar o logout:');
                        console.log(erro);
                    });
                }, 5000);
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

**logout_status.php:**

```
<?php
//session_start();
//$_SESSION['logout'] = 'on';
if (!empty($_SESSION['logout']))
    echo json_encode(
        array('logout' => $_SESSION['logout'])
    );
else
    echo json_encode(
        array('logout' => null)
    );
```

**Considerações sobre o exemplo:**

- Estou utilizando a biblioteca *jQuery 3.3.1*;
- Na página que trata a requisição do *ajax* (logout_status.php) deixei duas linhas comentadas a fim de testar o redirecionamento. Adapte conforme seu projeto...
- Na função `setInterval()` deixei o tempo definido em 5 segundos/5000 ms. Se quiser mudar, só alterar nessa linha: `}, 5000);`. Lembre-se que a função espera o tempo em microssegundos (ms);
- Já deixei o redirecionamento apontando para o arquivo `login.php`;
- O arquivo `logout_status.php` deve estar no mesmo diretório do `index.php` (lado-a-lado);

Pode baixar este projeto no meu [GitHub/LipESprY/sopt-verificar-valor-do-sessionlogout-sem-atualizar-a-pagina](https://github.com/lipespry/sopt-verificar-valor-do-sessionlogout-sem-atualizar-a-pagina).

Comment: Funcionou perfeitamente, obrigado ;)